# NotificationHub: Is there a way to retrieve/delete installations by PushChannel?

Tags: azure, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

In Azure `NotificationHub`, is there a way to retrieve/delete all installations (not the registration model) based on their `PushChannel`?

I have learned that `NotificationHub` has built-in de-duplication logic for installations. If I register with `InstallationId` of X on 2/13/2020 and then register again with `InstallationId` of Y on 2/14/2020 by using the same `PushChannel`, it seems that Azure will ignore the second installation when I send out a push to this second installation.

When a different user logs in on the same device, I want to uninstall the previous installation so that this user can get notifications. Tracking this on my end is difficult, so I'd rather go through `NotificationHub` APIs/SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Each Push Notification Service (FCM, APNS, etc) should take care of wrapping user login status for you. FCM documentation hints at that [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) where it says the registration token may change based on the user clearing app data.

Essentially, that just means that each installation ID being exposed to you by Azure Notification Hubs should already be associated with a particular user on a particular device, and you shouldn't need to track or manage this yourself.

Comment: You're right that the tokens might change. That's not the issue. The issue is when they don't change and multiple users sign out of my app and sign in on the same device. I registered User A with token X and then another user B registered on the same device with the same token. When I send a push to user B, it is never delivered because NH has two installations with the same token and the first one seems to be the only one working.

Comment: For FCM, I'm using this method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.sendfcmnativenotificationasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_NotificationHubs_NotificationHubClient_SendFcmNativeNotificationAsync_System_String_System_String_ In the `tagExpression`, I use `$InstallationId:{installationId}`. So, if I provide user B's `installationId`, it doesn't work.

Comment: I see, I may have misunderstood your scenario. If you're not relying on an account associated with the PNS operator, you can use the `DeleteInstallation` to remove a previously created installation as the user logs out.

Comment: Correct. That's if I can detect the user has logged out. What would happen if somehow the keystore data on the device was removed and the next time the app opens, the user login page is shown? In that case, I missed the opportunity to detect proper sign out for User A. Now, User B can register but not get notifications.

Comment: That said, I'd love to have an SDK method that allows me to retrieve all installations by `PushChannel` so that I could delete them on demand.